# WPF application changed scaling of the window

Tags: c#, wpf

I had a working C# application however, the scaling of the window has become very strange. For some reason, the window is smaller and the textboxes, texts etc are scaled down as well which makes everything seem a bit small. It was not like that before and in my workings, I did not change the size of the window anywhere. I have checked my past commits. Even if I go back to a very older branch, the window still remains the same small size.

Is it possible for a Visual Studio setting to have changed which is causing these scaling issues when I build my application? If so, how can I check them and fix that? The height and the width of the window remains the same but I can visibly see that the application itself is "smaller" now. Even if I change the height and width of the window, the scaling of the textboxes etc remains small.

```
<Page x:Class="Application.Main"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
      FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppInstaller"      
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="2000" d:DesignWidth="1000"
      Title="Main">
```

Comment: It depends on couple of thing, change in screen resolution might have impact on look & feel of your app. Your app is unable to scale as screen size due to fixed Width & Height of controls in your app

Comment: What parameters did you set for the Width and Height? Did you set automatic or a static number?

Comment: I've always used static height and width and it used to work fine. Now, even if I go back to an older branch, the issue still persists. I've posted the xaml code.

Comment: @AztecCodes please see my edit

Comment: Did you switch your monitor or did you switch the resolution of your monitor? Don't forget that these static sizes will look different on all kind of displays. This size could look good on a 1440p Monitor, but would look bad on a 1080p laptop.

Comment: It could also be due to a DPI scaling change in Windows settings.

Comment: All of these things have remained consistent. I published a release 2 weeks ago and everything was fine there. I've opened the .exe file of that release and it scales fine. However, now it's not- be it in Visual Studio or the .exe of the new release I'm working on. I've gone back to the branch of that said release as well and it's still small.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **SizeToContent** property which will automatically size your application regarding to the content. Different resolutions and displays would bring up a problem when you use static sizes, so this could be a good solution.

Check out the [MSDN for SizetoContent Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.sizetocontent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_Window_SizeToContent)

Code Example:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        …
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```